# Как сделать вертикальную линию?

Tags: html

Скажите, вот есть такой тег `<hr>` - это горизонтальная линия. А как сделать вертикальную?

Comment: [Как добавить на страницу вертикальную линию?](http://hashcode.ru/questions/1468/)

Answer (score 2):

Тег `<hr>` к PHP никакого отношения не имеет, это HTML.

А для всяких рамочек есть css свойства: `border`, `border-left`, `border-top`, и т.п.

Comment: А нам как-то на лекции препод сказал, что вертикальную линию можно сделать через hr! Нужно сделать size="100" например и длину в 1 пиксель... Вот такие бывают извращения.

Comment: Можно, но потом придется извращаться с позиционированием рядомстоящих элементов

Answer (score 1):

Оберни нужный текст в div с  классом 'v_line' и пропиши ему следующий стиль в css

```
.vline{
 border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

А подробнее почитай здесь:
http://htmlbook.ru/css/border-left

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:#0000FF;">данные внутри синей рамки</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще можно создать картинку 1x1px и сделать "background: url(...) repeat-y" к блоку.

Comment: Можно, но только это целесообразно использовать, если нужна какая-нибудь специфическая граница, фигурная (бантики, рюшечки и т.п.), а так все же лучше border'ом